# Application Insights No data since deployed to Azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure Application Insights.
After some config steps followed by official documents, I found my application insights works fine on my local build. The data of Request, Exception, Dependency and Custom Event all appear in azure portal.

However, as soon as I deploy it to Azure web app, I cannot see any Application Insights data in azure portal.

I've verified that the Application Insights Dlls and Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.dll are both copied to azure according to the "No (server) data since I published the app to my server" part of this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data/#q03

Some other strange things is, when I remote debug my azure web app, I found all TelemetryClient appears "not configured", however My Instrumentation key write correctly in ApplicationInsights.config

One more thing is, when I change code like this:

```
var client = new TelemetryClient();
client.Context.InstrumentationKey = "The Key";
client.TrackEvent("TestEvent");
```

The Custom Events comes out in Azure portal. But other data like Request, Exception, Dependencies are not recorded in portal automatically.

What's wrong with my Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the help of an azure support engineer, the problem has been solved.

The cause is that in App Setting in the azure portal, there is a config sets "MOBILESERVICESDOTNET_EXTENSION_VERSION" = 1.0.478

After delete this config, everything works fine.

But I'm still not sure the root cause of that. Why this config can cause so much trouble?

Comment: Well... I wouldn't have seen that coming

Comment: I ask my colleague and they told me this config is created when the mobile-app was created.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are recording telemetry where you have control over the TelemetryClient - like in your code sample above.

With that in mind, there are a few things for you to check:

- The applicationinsights.config is configured with your instrumentation key.
- The applicationinsights.config is being deployed to WebApps
- All the necessary telemetry modules are in your web.config

Since you're receiving telemetry locally, I would say this is as simple as you not deploying the applicationinsights.config file.

Comment: Hi, I have confirmed by Azure debugconsole that the applicationinsights.config is in my website's root folder(wwwroot/) with the correct instrumentation key. And the web.config is same as my local environment..

Comment: The web.config was edited automatically when I add application insights to my web app. Which add a "ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" module in <system.web> and remove then add a "ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" module in <system.webserver>

Comment: Is it possible for you to log on your azure instance and see if requests are going out to "dc.services.visualstudio.com" and getting 200's back?

Answer (score 0):

I found additional troubleshooting help in Kudo, at https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationInsights

I ended up actually removing all code that does the Application Insights integration (including deleting ApplicationInsights.config), and instead letting the app service handle that automatically. I might not be a solution for op due to custom events, bur for standard tracking it worked like a charm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32259810)